# Mapbox crash Android 8 (Oreo)

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I have been using Mapbox version 4.2.2 as I am not yet prepared to move to Mapbox 5 as a few features from version 4 don't seem to be supported. (In specific [Camera Tracking](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/issues/259))

I have found that I am getting crashes regarding Android 8 devices.

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.sctaylor.map/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.telemetry.TelemetryService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{3534d78 u0a235 CEM  idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
   at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1512)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1468)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:644)
   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.telemetry.MapboxEventManager.setTelemetryEnabled(MapboxEventManager.java:252)
   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.telemetry.MapboxEventManager.initialize(MapboxEventManager.java:146)
   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.MapboxAccountManager.start(MapboxAccountManager.java:50)
   at com.sctaylor.map.AnalyticsApplication.onCreate(AnalyticsApplication.java:44)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5821)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1669)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6580)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

It looks like this is an issue with Android 8's background service restrictions (Need to use a job scheduler). Is there a way to fix this without upgrading to Mapbox 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks like this is an issue with Android 8's background service
>   restrictions (Need to use a job scheduler). Is there a way to fix this
>   without upgrading to Mapbox 5?

You are completely right about the cause of the issue.

The issue was reported [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/10900) on GitHub, updates will be propagated [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-android/issues/55).

The clean fix is for Mapbox to implement JobScheduler. However, they have not released the fix yet and I don't know if they will fix it for versions 4.x

As a contemporary fix, they just caught the `IllegalStateException` while Mapbox still seems to work.

Using the try/catch approach around `MapboxAccountManager.start()` does not seem to be a good idea because code subsequent to `setTelemetryEnabled()` would not be executed.

The only workaround I see is degrading the targetSdkVersion to 25.

Comment: Great idea, I am going to push out an update now and report back with how it goes!

Comment: I was facing the exact same problem. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: @SCTaylor Could you reproduce the bug before you downgraded the targetSDKversion?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it consistently but I did see it once in the emulator. Not ever on an actual device though.

Comment: I am having the same issue in android 8.0 oreo